# How to add File path in NanoHTTPD response

Tags: android

I am using NanoHTTPD to play audio file from my sdcard,It works fine.

If i put http://172.16.6.75:8080 in my browser it starts playing but i want to play the exact file like http://172.16.6.75:8080/test.mp3.

Hope someone can help me here. Thanks!

Comment: You should provide some code how you play the audio file.

Comment: It 's automatically gets played once i put  http://172.16.6.75:8080/ in  browser,but i want to separate for each file,i want to play only the link append with test.mp3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Well, finally I change serve method to have 2 URLS and distinguish between them:

@Override
public Response serve(String uri, Method method,
                      Map<String, String> header,
                      Map<String, String> parameters,
                      Map<String, String> files) {


 if (uri.contains("picture")){          
 //serve the picture 
      return new NanoHTTPD.Response(st, mediasend, fisPicture, f.length());

 }else if (uri.contains("song")){

 //serve the song
      return new NanoHTTPD.Response(st, mediasend, fisSong, f.length());
 }
```